# SQL Query with part of the key possibly being NULL

Tags: sql, null, subquery

I've been working on a SQL query which needs to pull a value with a two-column key, where one of the columns may be null.And if it's null, I want to pick that value only if there is no row with the specific key

So.
CUSTOM_____PLAN_____COST
VENDCO_____LMNK_____50
VENDCO_____null_____25
BALLCO_____null_____10

I'm trying to run a query that will pull this into one field, i.e.,  the value of VENDCO at 50, and the value of BUYCO at 10, ignoring the VENDCO row with 25.  This would be as part of a joined subquery, so I can't use the actual keys of VENDCO/BUYCO etc.  Essentially, pick the cost value with the plan if it exists, but the one where it's null if the plan is not there.

It might also be worthwhile to point out that if I "select * from table where PLAN is null" I don't get results -- I have to select where PLAN=''.  I'm not sure if that indicates anything weird about the data.

Hope I'm making myself clear.

Comment: Tag DB, add input data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

I think that `not exists` should do what you want:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    plan is not null
    or not exists (
        select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.custom = t.custom and t1.plan is not null
    )
```

Basically this gives priority to rows where `plan` is not null in groups sharing the same `custom`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=22fc4beada089d381d4a0cc219540bec)**:

```
CUSTOM | PLAN | COST
:----- | :--- | ---:
VENDCO | LMNK |   50
BALLCO | null |   10
```